# Hyphenation of words preceded by a symbol

Tags: hyphenation

I need to emphasize certain words or groups of words using bold and putting a symbol before them. Here is a minimum working example, where I defined the command `\term` as follows (here I use a bullet):

```
\documentclass[12pt,b5paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=5.5cm}
\newcommand{\term}[1]{$\bullet$\textbf{#1}} 
\begin{document}

It is a truth universally \term{acknowledged}, that a single man in 
possession of a good fortune must be in want of a wife. However little 
known the feelings or views of such a man may be on his first entering 
a neighbourhood

\end{document}
```

When the first word in `\term` is at the end of a line, it is never hyphenated. I suspect there's some internal rule in LaTeX so that a word preceded by a symbol in `$...$`, with no space in between, is not hyphenated. How can this be overcome?

Comment: Can you make a minimal working example for testing?

Comment: Use `\hspace{0pt}` between the bullet and the bold word.

Comment: Great! Thank you. If you put it as an answer, I can accept it and vote it

Comment: @Johannes_B `\nolinebreak\hspace{0pt}` is safer.